# Django Serve Static Files with out seperate Web server(i.e, without nginx??)

Tags: nginx, django-rest-framework, django-staticfiles, django-deployment, django-dev-server

I have a issue with running my django application on the production server, Its working fine when i use nginx webserver to serve the static files.

But i have my django application running on one server and my webserver is running on other server.So, i cannot configure nginx to serve the static files.

I Want to know is there any way to serve the Django static files which using nginx server? I mean django should directly serve the static files for my application.

Answer (score 1):

Use `whiteNoise`. WhiteNoise is a package which will help you to serve the staticfiles with very ease.
http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Let me check it once. But I have a doubt, If i use whitenoise, then i dont get any requirement to use nginx right??

Comment: If the problem is only with the static files, then yes, whiteNoise will handle all of that. You don't need any other requirement. But do the setup in a proper manner as shown in the link. Please leave an upvote if it helps and mark it as accepted.